# How do I get selenium to click on a dynamic button?

Tags: python, selenium, dynamic, jupyter-notebook

I am unable to make selenium click on this button because it does not appear in the html retrieved with driver.Chrome() as it is a dynamic button
[screen capture of button I want to click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmfXB.png)

This is the webpage link: http://data.cnmc.es/datagraph/jsp/inf_trim.jsp

How could I complete this task in python in Jupyter Notebook?

Thanks for your time

Jaime

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag is in `iframe`, Please switch to `iframe` first like below :

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("http://data.cnmc.es/datagraph/jsp/inf_trim.jsp")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "frame[name='Lateral']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "29097"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```